# Error in textSearchEnable=true in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am getting the below error when enabling text search in mongodb. Any Suggestion.

I have mongo.config filw which contains :

```
##store data here
dbpath=C:\mongodb\data

##all output go here
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

##log read and write operations
diaglog=3
```

Error is :

```
C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\bin>mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.336 [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=976 port=27017 dbpath=\data\db\ 64-bit host=dellvostro3
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] db version v2.4.6
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] git version: b9925db5eac369d77a3a5f5d98a145eaaacd9673
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] build info: windows sys.getwindowsversion(major=6, minor=1, build=7601, platform=2, service_pack='Service Pack
 1') BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] allocator: system
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] options: { setParameter: [ "textSearchEnabled=true" ] }
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.337 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 10296
*********************************************************************
 ERROR: dbpath (\data\db\) does not exist.
 Create this directory or give existing directory in --dbpath.
 See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/startingandstoppingmongo
*********************************************************************
, terminating
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 dbexit:
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: lock for final commit...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
Tue Jan 14 16:52:51.338 dbexit: really exiting now
```

Answer (score 1):

You provide wrong path to your data

```
 ERROR: dbpath (\data\db\) does not exist.
```

`\data\db\` is default mongo data path, you need to create this directory or get provide another path  when running `mongod`

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

MongoDB will take `\data\db\` as the dbpath. Which is not there in your machine and hence you get the error.

I see you have a config file containing the dbpath etc, but you haven't specified the config file while starting mongod.

```
mongod --config mongo.config --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
```

See using config file [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/mongod/#cmdoption--config).

Also you could move the textSearchEnabled=true to your config file.

```
##store data here
dbpath=C:\mongodb\data

##all output go here
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

##log read and write operations
diaglog=3

setParameter=textSearchEnabled=true
```

Now you can start mongod by just using

```
mongod --config mongo.config
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, Now i am getting the below error :  C:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2.4.6\bin>mongod --config  C:\mongodb\mongo.config --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
(next Line)error command line: unknown option textSearchEnabled . Also i have db directory inside C:\mongodb\data

Comment: I have edited my answer(Made a correction in the config file). I understand you have updated the config file. Pls correct it and run `mongod --config C:\mongodb\mongo.config`

Comment: In you case, `\data\db\ ` is `C:\data\db\ ` not `C:\mongodb\data\db\ `.

Comment: Thanks now script got executed.